# Readout properties of a ms word document on a linux system

Tags: linux, scripting, ms-word

We want to program a pre-commit hook on our linux based svn server which executes some checks on the properties of ms word documents (e.g. author, version, etc.) during their initial check-in.

Is there any way to read out these properties with some e.g. scripting language or C++ code on a linux system?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of Word you're working with, possibly.

The DOCX format is really a ZIP file which contains a number of files (many XML) that make up the Word document. It's [based on the Office Open XML format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx). If you unzip it and look in the `docProps` directory that's created, `core.xml` contains several nodes that may be of use to you: `dc:creator`, `cp:lastModifiedBy`, `cp:revision`. Interrogate those with your scripting language/XML library of choice.